# Regular expression to match identical repeated digits in phone numbers

Tags: php, mysql, preg-match

Sorry if the title wasnt descriptive enough. I have a bunch of phone numbers in a mysql database. Dont know if there is a query to do this or better to use something like preg_match with PHP. But I need to search using a pattern like so:

Ends with XXXX
or
Contains 4XXX

The X means the same number. So if I searched for Ends with XXXX Im looking for any number like so:

671-0000

421-5555

789-1111

If I search Contains 4XXX then Im looking for any number like so:

345-4111

156-4777

For some reason I cant wrap my brain around this. Seems like it would be pretty easy. Can anyone help? Appreciate it!

Comment: What's wrong with `preg_match`? You can also use `RLIKE` in MySQL.

Comment: @tadman Nothing wrong with it, Im asking what type of pattern to use with preg_match to dynamically search for those type of patterns. Some will type in 4xxx into the search field and I need to then need to know what search pattern to find phone numbers that match that. X means it could be any number 0-9 and they are the same. So XXX means it has to bee either 999 or 000 or 333 3xxx means it has to be 3111 or 3555. How can I do that via preg_match?

Comment: Ah, that makes a lot more sense. I've edited your title to, I hope, better explain your intent here.

Comment: @tadman Yeah I knew my title was not very good. But as I mentioned, I couldnt wrap my brain around it so I couldnt figure out what to even ask properly. In fact as you saw in my last response to you, I cant even type properly. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest expression here for the NXXX pattern is:

```
\d(\d)\1{2}
```

If the regular expression engine you're using supports that kind of back-tracking with `\1`, which references whatever digit happens to be in the `(\d)` spot, then this should work [as in this example](https://regex101.com/r/5W6LLn/1).

You could also adapt that for the XXXX pattern like:

```
(\d)\1{3}
```

Where that's three repeated, identical digits after the first.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Before I mark it as the answer, one last question containing to this. Is there a way to check for if its a duplicate or by itself? For example, say someone searches like so: 333-X123. Is there a way to check if there is only 1 X vs just only searching if they had XX or XXX or XXXX?

Comment: `333-\d123` will match for any X, if that's what you mean. For repeated X you need to capture it and back-reference it.

Comment: I think I was asking the wrong question in my last response. After messing around here is what I need help with. Can you do the \1 multiple times in preg_match? For example I have 544-311-4888 I have this as the pattern to search 5(\d)\1{1}\-3(\d)\1{1}\-4(\d)\1{2} But it doesnt find it. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Oh, each time you capture you need to increment the associated back-reference. So `(\d)\1\1-(\d)\2\2\2` would match `XXX-YYYY` pattern numbers. `\1` is simply the *first* back-refrence, `\2` the second and so on.

Comment: That was it. Geez I just feel like I should of known this. Thanks so much for your help!